# Clone multisession DVD

Tags: windows, optical-media

I am looking for a software (preferrably free) that allows me to simply clone multisession DVDs. I have a set of back-up DVDs for my system which I would like to replicate to store in a different location than my original copies.
Ideally, I just want to pop in the original DVD and a writable DVD and obtain an exact copy. Any thoughts?

Comment: One word of warning - multi session - un-finalized optical disks often don't work on other devices or after a system restore/reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

The best software I've used for multi-session DVD is:

[Cheetah DVD Burner](http://www.cheetahburner.com/Features.aspx)

Multi-session DVD discs may not be readable by some operating systems below Windows XP.

Multi-session DVD discs may not be readable if the subsequent sessions exceed 2.0GB. The first session can be of any allowable size. This rule only applies to DVD-R and DVD+R.

**References**

- [Cheetah Burner FAQ](http://www.cheetahburner.com/faq.html)
- [CDR FAQ](http://www.cdrfaq.org/faq06.html)